# Drawing content over safearea in material3 with jetpack compose does not work

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-statusbar, jetpack-compose-accompanist

I am using the latest `BOM` version of `jetpack compose: implementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.06.01')` align with `materail3`. I need my content to ignore safe area. I have already tried the solution of using accompanist library for this

In `MainActivity.kt` I added

```
WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
```

Inside my `composable` I added

```
val systemUiController = rememberSystemUiController()
    val useDarkIcons = !isSystemInDarkTheme()

    DisposableEffect(systemUiController, useDarkIcons) {
        // Update all of the system bar colors to be transparent, and use
        // dark icons if we're in light theme
        systemUiController.setSystemBarsColor(
            color = Color.Transparent,
            darkIcons = useDarkIcons
        )

        // setStatusBarColor() and setNavigationBarColor() also exist

        onDispose {}
    }
```

I also tried adding

```
 Scaffold(
        content = {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(it.calculateTopPadding())
            ) {....
```

But still my content does not ignore safe area. In short I just need to hide the default status bar so my image can occupy entire height

Comment: share some reference image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I got it correctly you wanted to achieve the following behavior :

[image]

If so, there 4 steps to achieve this.

It seems you didn't play around with WindowInsets =) (see point **#3**)

**#1** In Activity before setContent{} add

```kotlin
 WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
```

```kotlin
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
        setContent {
            val darkModeState by darkModeState.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

            AppTheme(darkTheme = darkModeState) {
                MainApp()
            }
        }
    }
```

**#2** In the app theme set the status bar as transparent

```kotlin
  window.statusBarColor = Color.Transparent.toArgb()
```

```kotlin
@Composable
fun AppTheme(
    darkTheme: Boolean = true,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    val colorScheme = when {
        darkTheme -> DarkColorScheme
        else -> LightColorScheme
    }
    val view = LocalView.current
    if (!view.isInEditMode) {
        SideEffect {
            val window = (view.context as Activity).window
            window.statusBarColor = Color.Transparent.toArgb()
            window.navigationBarColor = Color.Transparent.toArgb()
            WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, view).isAppearanceLightStatusBars = !darkTheme
            WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, view).isAppearanceLightNavigationBars = !darkTheme

        }
    }

    MaterialTheme(
        colorScheme = colorScheme,
        typography = Typography
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background)
        ) {
            content()
        }
    }
}
```

**#3** In Scaffold() set insets to 0 (you can play around with it if you don't need 0 for all sides)

```kotlin
contentWindowInsets = WindowInsets(0.dp, 0.dp, 0.dp, 0.dp)
```

```kotlin
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(
    nestedNavGraph: @Composable () -> Unit,
    bottomBar: @Composable () -> Unit
) {

    Scaffold(bottomBar = bottomBar,
        contentWindowInsets = WindowInsets(0.dp, 0.dp, 0.dp, 0.dp)
    ) { paddingValues ->
        ScreenBackground(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(paddingValues)
        ) {
            nestedNavGraph.invoke()
        }
    }
}
```

**#4** Don't forget to remove Modifier.safeContentPadding() or .safeDrawingPadding() everywhere if there is.

Hoping it would help.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly control the visibility of the status bar by using system UI flags. In your MainActivity.kt (or whatever the Activity hoisting the view is), add the following code snippet:

```
 window.decorView.systemUiVisibility =
    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE or
    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
```

Comment: systemUiVisibility is deprecated